# Vertically align text in bootstrap styled labels and links

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I tried using bootstrap button styled labels and links with a bigger a hight than default und the text is vertically aligned at the upper side of the button. If I do the same with an actual button element, it is centered vertically.

How do I center the text vertically?

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<label class="btn btn-primary" style="height: 80px; margin-bottom: 0">Label Button</label>
<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" style="height: 80px; margin-bottom: 0">Link Button</a>
<button class="btn btn-primary" style="height: 80px">Actual Button</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add this line to the class of the button:

```
line-height: 60px;
```

Or you can do this:

```
display: inline-flex;
align-items: center;
```

As in the snippet bellow.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<label class="btn btn-primary" style=" display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
     height: 80px; margin-bottom: 0">Label Button</label>
<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" style="line-height: 60px; height: 80px; margin-bottom: 0">Link Button</a>
<button class="btn btn-primary" style="height: 80px">Actual Button</button>
```

Comment: Line height is not a proper way to do it, if the button height changes, again the line height needs to adjusted.

Comment: First, he can add it in the css class of the button, and can change it if it's necessary together with the height of the button. Second, he did not specify if the buttons height will be changed again in the process, and that was the only reason why I choose this answer, other than that, you are right

Comment: Awesome to see that you took my suggestion in a positive way. Kudos!

Comment: Not only that, I improved the answer, now it has another option that does not depend on the buttons height :)

Comment: Unfortunately not :(

Comment: thumbs up for the try though.! :)

Answer (score -1):

Set :

```
vertical-align:middle;
line-height:80px; //height of your parent element
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<label class="btn btn-primary" style="vertical-align:middle;line-height:80px;">Label Button</label>
<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" style="vertical-align:middle;line-height:80px;">Link Button</a>
<button class="btn btn-primary" style="vertical-align:middle;line-height:80px;">Actual Button</button>
```

Comment: You have a typo in your style attribute ('vetical-align'). Still works, so maybe 'line-height:80px;' is enough?

Comment: sorry, it's 'vertical-align'. and yes, setting your line-height according to your parent element always aligns it to the middle vertically.